# Lazysodium for Java cannot initialize sodium object

Tags: encryption

Following the tutorial from [documentation](https://docs.lazycode.co/lazysodium/usage/getting-started) I added the lazysodium library with Maven but seem like lazycode is trying to load another class but cannot find it. 
Error message

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: co/libly/resourceloader/SharedLibraryLoader
    at com.goterl.lazycode.lazysodium.utils.LibraryLoader.loadBundledLibrary(LibraryLoader.java:115)
    at com.goterl.lazycode.lazysodium.utils.LibraryLoader.loadLibrary(LibraryLoader.java:84)
    at com.goterl.lazycode.lazysodium.SodiumJava.<init>(SodiumJava.java:34)
    at com.goterl.lazycode.lazysodium.SodiumJava.<init>(SodiumJava.java:23)
    at aitmed.crypto.main(crypto.java:12)
```

This is my main class, I make the simplest class possible to just test the library.

```
package groupme;

import com.goterl.lazycode.lazysodium.*;


public class crypto {


    public static void main(String args[])  {


        LazySodiumJava lazySodium = new LazySodiumJava(new SodiumJava());
    }

}
```

This is my pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>aitmed</groupId>
    <artifactId>androidsdk</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <properties>
        <!-- required for jdk9 -->
        <maven.compiler.source>1.7</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>1.7</maven.compiler.target>

        <java.version>1.11</java.version>
        <maven.compiler.source>1.11</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>1.11</maven.compiler.target>
    </properties>

    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>lazysodium-java</id>
            <url>https://dl.bintray.com/terl/lazysodium-maven</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>


    <dependencies>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.goterl.lazycode</groupId>
            <artifactId>lazysodium-java</artifactId>
            <version>4.2.3</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.java.dev.jna</groupId>
            <artifactId>jna</artifactId>
            <version>5.4.0</version>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

</project>
```

Comment: There also seems to be a runtime dependency to [co.libly, section _Runtime Dependencies_](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.goterl.lazycode/lazysodium-java/4.2.2) (as specified in the exception) that probably needs to be added.

Comment: I opened an issue and got a resolution in https://github.com/terl/lazysodium-java/issues/60